# Why is there used adverb?

Tags: adverbs

I came across this sentence below:

> Judithe Hernandez’s art career began in Los Angeles during the **socially and politically** turbulent 1960s

I know that adverb is mainly used to modify verb or adjective or adverb but in this case I don't know what it modifies

Comment: ***socially*** and ***politically*** are ["adverbially" modifying the adjective](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/#:~:text=An%20adverb%20is%20a%20word,same%20as%20their%20adjective%20counterparts.) ***turbulent*** (which itself "adjectivally" modifies the noun *[the] **1960s***).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Shouldn't that be an Answer rather than a comment?

Comment: No. I don't know what definitions of "adverb" and "adjective" OP is working with, and I *certainly* don't have a clear-cut pair of mutually exclusive definitions available myself. That's why my comment is littered with "scare quotes".

Comment: I don't understand why you are hedging. Surely 'socially' is modifying 'turbulent'. Doesn't that make it a clear-cut case of it being an adverb modifying an adjective? What kind of mutually exclusive definitions of adverbs exist such that we cannot categorise a word as an adverb? Just asking.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you for the explanation. I'm satisfied with what you said. I incorrectly defined **turbulent** as a noun, and I was confused by it.

Comment: The noun form (which would indeed be modified by straight adjectives) is *...during the social and political **turbulence of the** 1960s*.